# How do I make every second row in table take up the space of all cells?

Tags: html, css

I have a table with information from the log in my database and when you click a button you get extra information about that specific log item. When you click the "info" button (see image below) it will show this information.

The problem is that the information loaded will only take up the width of the "message" column and not the entire width of the table.

TL;DR: How do I make my row take up the space of all the cells?

[image: The log table shown on website]

**_LogPartialLayout.cshtml**

```
<div class="table" id="logtable">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell" id="tableth">
            message
        </div>
        <div class="cell" id="tableth">
            timestamp
        </div>
        <div class="cell" id="tableth">
            level
        </div>
        <div class="cell" id="tableth">
            customerName
        </div>
        <div class="cell" id="tableth">

        </div>
    </div>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Logs)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell" id="tabletd">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.message)
            </div>
            <div class="cell" id="tabletd">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.timeStamp)
            </div>
            <div class="cell" id="tabletd">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.level)
            </div>
            <div class="cell" id="tabletd">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </div>
            <div class="cell" id="tabletd">
                <input type="button" id="extra-info-button" name="answer" value="Info" onclick="showDiv(@item.id.ToString())" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
                <div id="@item.id.ToString()" style="display:none;" class="answer_list">
                    <strong>Uri:</strong><br /> @item.Uri <br /><br />
                    <strong>Method:</strong><br /> @item.Method <br /><br />
                    <strong>HttpStatus:</strong><br /> @item.HttpStatus <br /><br />
                    <strong>RequestHeaders:</strong><br /> @item.RequestHeaders <br /><br />
                    <strong>RequestContent:</strong><br /> @item.RequestContent <br /><br />
                    <strong>ResponseHeaders:</strong><br /> @item.ResponseHeaders <br /><br />
                    <strong>ResponseContent:</strong><br /> @item.ResponseContent <br /><br />
                </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

**StyleSheet.css**

```
.table { display: table; }
.row { display: table-row; }
.cell { display: table-cell; }

.answer_list{
    font-family: monospace;
    text-align:left;
    /*word-wrap: break-word;*/
    /* Warning: Needed for oldIE support, but words are broken up letter-by-letter */
    -ms-word-break: break-all;
    word-break: break-all;

     /* Non standard for webkit */
    word-break: break-word;

    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
    border-left: solid 1px black; 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `colspan` attribute on the table cell you want to span multiple columns.

**EDIT**: I see you're not using `<table>` but actually *abusing* the `<div>` element as a kind of table.

Please, please change your HTML to use `<table>` as it is intended for data tables, which this is:

```
<table id="logtable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>message</th>
            <th>timestamp</th>
            <th>level</th>
            <th>customerName</th>
            <th></th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
 @foreach (var item in Model.Logs)
 {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.message)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.timeStamp)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.level)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
            <td><input type="button" id="extra-info-button" name="answer" value="Info" onclick="showDiv(@item.id.ToString())" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="@item.id.ToString()" style="display:none;" class="answer_list" colspan="5">
                    <strong>Uri:</strong><br /> @item.Uri <br /><br />
                    <strong>Method:</strong><br /> @item.Method <br /><br />
                    <strong>HttpStatus:</strong><br /> @item.HttpStatus <br /><br />
                    <strong>RequestHeaders:</strong><br /> @item.RequestHeaders <br /><br />
                    <strong>RequestContent:</strong><br /> @item.RequestContent <br /><br />
                    <strong>ResponseHeaders:</strong><br /> @item.ResponseHeaders <br /><br />
                    <strong>ResponseContent:</strong><br /> @item.ResponseContent <br /><br />
                </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How would I apply this to my code exactly?  I tried adding <div class="cell" colspan="5"> around the <div id="@item.id.ToString()" style="display:none;" class="answer_list"> and it had no effect. And I also tried adding it like this: <div class="row" colspan="5"> - also with no effect.

Comment: @DanAndersson I have updated my answer. You need to use `<table>` instead of `<div>`

Comment: Yes this works perfectly. Now I'm pretty sad I spent hours changing from table to divs because a lot of people told me that was needed to have a dynamic table to add the "more information" divs that only were shown when the button was pressed...

Comment: @DanAndersson Those people were wrong and gave you bad advice, I'm sorry to say.